# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using solr-solrj-3.6.1.jar

Tags: solrj

Using Solrj to connect to solr indexes. Used jar **solr-solrj-3.6.1.jar** which I got by adding below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
   <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I see that CommonsHttpSolrServer is deprecated and hence using HttpSolrServer . During run time i get the below error,
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient

Just adding **solr-solrj-3.6.1.jar** is not sufficient? Should I have to add more dependencies? I also tried adding httpclient 4.1, It started asking for org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added below dependencies to get this working

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this package to your maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

My simple project of solrj uses the following dependencies:

```
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
          <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
          <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

Between, Maven can automatically download them (for example, I started the Java Application of Maven in NetBeans, and then just added the dependencies). Additionally, I needed just to download the library of commons-logging 1.1.3 (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi). You can read more about libraries and dependencies here: (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).