# Adding SolrJ library to Grails 3 is causing NoClassDefFoundError error

Tags: solrj, grails3, grails3.2.0

When I added SolrJ to Grails 3.2.4, And when I create the client, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`

Dependency I added:
`compile group: 'org.apache.solr', name: 'solr-solrj', version: '7.5.0'`

Stack Trace is as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createPoolingConnectionManager(HttpClientUtil.java:260)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:255)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.<init>(HttpSolrClient.java:200)
        at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$Builder.build(HttpSolrClient.java:951)
        at (TestController.groovy:40)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Any Idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try to add the more dependencies, for httpclient, httpcore & httpmime. You could check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312463/getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-using-solr-solrj-3-6-1-jar if it works for you.

Comment: I already tried it. It did not help.

Comment: what version of those library tried those http libs. I suppose solr has some dependency on version of those files.

Comment: these are solr-libs file coming with solr distribution 7.4 https://imgur.com/a/GIlmLYh. try all those if it helps!

Comment: Will try and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: I actually have an older version of httpClient and for some reason, IntelliJ wasn't properly getting the newer version when I updated the gradle file. Running it via command line worked. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Good to hear that!